# Git push master fatal: You are not currently on a branch

Tags: git, github

Master is it at say commit #10. However, I ended up realizing I broke something along the way that wasn't caught by tests.

I ended up going to commit #5, and then slowly re-did the dev of each commit and adjusted it continually to ensure it didn't re-cause the bug. Now I'm essentially back to commit #10, but with a number of changes that prevent the bug from happening.

I now want to create commit #11 using my changes. But when I try to push to master I get

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push master HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

Which is to be expected. But how do I actually get that to push up to my remote branch?

I tried `git push origin HEAD:master` but then got this:

```
! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/tomhammond/sample.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I do a `git status` I see `HEAD detached from 4a74ac3`

Comment: Have you ensured that your commit history until #10 is what it was originally, and that only your commit #11 contains the changes? An error like that is normally given when your branch and the origin branch have a different commit history (like what happens when you re-did the dev of each of the commits)

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't. I think I foolishly started doing the dev after checking out #5

Comment: That's fine, what you can do is `git reset [commit10Hash]` to unstage your changes, then `git stash` to save them for a bit, `git reset --hard origin/nameofremotebranch` to reset it to origin, `git stash pop` to reapply the changes you want, then `git add .` and `git commit -m "Your new changes on top of origin"`. You should then be able to `git push origin nameofremotebranch` without conflict

Answer (score 166, accepted):

> But when I try to push to master I get

`fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)`

> Which is to be expected

Working in a detached state is *not* to be expected, unless you deliberately want to be doing this, which I doubt is the case for you.  Instead of checking out commit #5, you should have either reverted the `master` branch to that commit, or do a `git rebase` in interactive mode where you can rehash the commits as you want.

That being said, if you are certain that the version of `master` in the detached state is what you *really* want to keep, then you can get around the `non-fast-forward` error, by force pushing the branch to the remote:

```
git push origin HEAD:master --force
```

However, if you force push you run the risk of causing problems for all other users who have that branch checked out.  A less risky solution would be to create a temporary branch from the detached HEAD, and then merge that branch into `master`:

```
git branch temp-branch
git checkout master
git merge temp-branch
git push origin master
```

Comment: But doesn't this create issues for other developers who want to check out `master`?

Answer (score 12):

have you ensured that you really in a branch? use `git branch` and check if you are in a branch. if not, just `git checkout branch-name-you-want` and then `git push` is fine!

Comment: While a very simple answer, this is usually what fixes most of the problems leading to the OP's question. In my case, I had reverted back to an earlier commit, fixed some issues, and did a few pushes — but forgot that the HEAD was still detached! Your solution fixed everything for me. Thanks 

Answer (score 4):

`git push` will only let you fast-forward the remote. This means the commit you are trying to push needs to be a descendent of the remote branch. Since you edited the previous commits after 5, you don't have a descendent but more of a cousin. You can give `git push --force` if you want to overwrite the branch, but if other people have made their own changes on top of the current master, they won't be able to pull the branch anymore. Also, if someone else pushes to master before you do, their changes will be lost. Generally, you don't want to force push if you are not the only one using a branch.

Comment: Great info - I'm actually the only one working on this right now so I think that should work

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch and you can merge these changes in the previous branch

```
git checkout -b newBranch 
git checkout previousBranch
git merge newBranch
git push origin previousBranch
git branch -d previousBranch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing to a new repository you can use

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/main --force
```

`main` here is a new branch that will be created in case your target repository is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work if you want do it without rebase

```
git config pull.rebase false 
git pull origin master
git add .
git commit -m "Your Commit message"
git push
```

Now your good to go   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch to retain the commits you created and then push them to the remote.

Use this command:

git switch -c < new-branch-name >

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to loose your work on the detached head, run:

```
git switch -c my_changes
git switch main
git merge my_changes
```

This create new branch from the detached head. Then add those changes to main branch (you can change `main` to `master` or any branch you want).