# Unable to remove last commit from remote repository on BeanstalkApp

Tags: git

I am working with a remote repository on BeanstalkApp and am trying to remove the last commit that was pushed to that repo.

I was able to reset my last commit on my local repository by using the following command:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

This command worked fine.  Now that I have my local repo back to where it was before this commit, I want to push this master branch to the remote Repo on BeanstalkApp.

I tried using the following command:

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

After pushing my repo back onto the Master branch, I did not see the last commit removed from the remote repo.

Is there a step I'm missing in performing this process?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might need to force push, but changing public history should generally be avoided.

Comment: @crashmstr I edited my `git push` command from above and actually tried using the `--force` command but that didn't make any differences.

Comment: better to make revert instead reset

Comment: @Alexan The weird thing is I reset my local repo and when I run `git log`, I can see on my local machine that the last commit was actually removed successfully.

Comment: try `git push origin master  --force'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768381/240564

Comment: @Alexan I did some more research and it appears that I'm working with a detached head such as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471557/git-push-master-fatal-you-are-not-currently-on-a-branch

Comment: did you get any message during push?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155550/discussion-between-jeff-p-and-alexan).