# fatal: You are not currently on a branch.git push master HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>

Tags: git

I am facing git issue following below...

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

git push master HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

What shall I do?

Comment: maybe same problem as [#30471557](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471557/git-push-master-fatal-you-are-not-currently-on-a-branch). You can find helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head)

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that you on the correct commit *locally*, then you can just do:

```
git push origin HEAD:master --force
```

And then, importantly, change your pointer from the detached head to the current head by:

```
git branch --force master HEAD
git checkout master
```

This assumes that you have done the following steps if you wanted to revert to a previous commit which is named "target commit" in the following (as "previous commit" is ambiguous, it could be any previous commit):

```
git reset --hard <target commit>
```

You have checked out the code of that commit by:

```
git checkout <target commit>
```

If that gives you:

```
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

<unknown commit> revert to <target commit>
```

THEN do the `git reset` command above again!

IF `git status` says:

```
HEAD detached at <target commit>
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

THEN you are ready to push with the command above:

```
git push origin HEAD:master --force
```